# F# - Is this a good way to validate and keep a value between two bounds?

Tags: validation, f#

I have various values which I would like to keep between certain bounds: e.g. Width of Column from 10 to 50 inclusive; or Number Of Rows from 1 to 100 inclusive. The values are coming from a process external to my F# code.

When a given value falls below the lower bound I would like the value to be given the minimum bound value.
When the given value shoots above the upper bound I would like the value to be given the maximum bound value.
Otherwise I would accept the given value.

For example:

Bounds = 10 to 50 – Given Value = 3 – Result Value = 10

Bounds = 10 to 50 – Given Value = 200 – Result Value = 50

Bounds = 10 to 50 – Given Value = 32 – Result Value = 32

I have come up with some code but I’m not sure if it is taking things too far or whether I am doing it a silly way.
It look like it’s easy to reason how it’s working but I’m not sure about it, for no reason that I can put my finger on.

```
type ValueAndBounds = { Value : int; Lower : int; Upper: int }

let (|TooSmall|TooLarge|CorrectSize|) input =
    if input.Value < input.Lower then TooSmall
    elif input.Value > input.Upper then TooLarge
    else CorrectSize

let keepWithinBounds input =
    match input with
    | TooSmall -> input.Lower
    | TooLarge -> input.Upper
    | CorrectSize -> input.Value

type ColumnWidth = ColumnWidth of int

let width = ColumnWidth (keepWithinBounds { Value = 32; Lower = 10; Upper = 50 })
```

Is there some way I can improve this?

Have I gone too far for this sort of simple thing (is it more than necessary)?

Is there a better way to do this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s my own answer which uses both active patterns, and partial application, and allows for generic use without the need for an extra type.

```
let (|TooSmall|TooLarge|CorrectSize|) (lower, upper, input) =
   if input < lower then TooSmall
   elif input > upper then TooLarge
   else CorrectSize
 
let keepWithinBounds lowerBound upperBound input =
   match (lowerBound, upperBound, input) with
   | TooSmall -> lowerBound
   | TooLarge -> upperBound
   | CorrectSize -> input
 
type ColumnWidth = ColumnWidth of int
type RowHeight = RowHeight of int
type Temperature = Temperature of float
 
let createColumnWidth = keepWithinBounds 10 40
let createRowHeight = keepWithinBounds 60 100
let createTemperature = keepWithinBounds 0.0 20.0
 
let width = ColumnWidth (createColumnWidth 50)
let height = RowHeight (createRowHeight 50)
let temp = Temperature (createTemperature 33.1)

//val width : ColumnWidth = ColumnWidth 40
//val height : RowHeight = RowHeight 60
//val temp : Temperature = Temperature 20.0
```

Answer (score 2):

personally I'd just define a simple function, and use a bit of partial application,

```
let keepWithBounds min max value = 
    if (value < min) then
        min
    elif (value > max) then
        max
    else 
        value
```

then your code can do something like

```
let handleWidth = keepWithBounds 10 50
let width1 = handleWidth 32
let width2 = handleWidth 60
```

Comment: Ah, yes, partial application, that’s probably the way to go with this. Less code, less messing around, and it’s much more generic this way. (At least I learned a tiny bit about active patterns along the way so I didn’t totally waste my time going down the direction I did.) Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: I don't massively use active patterns, I would do say if they create a useful abstraction that I wanted to use more than say...5 times...I accept my "if" statement is a bit ugly.

Comment: I wouldn’t say that your ‘if’ statement was "ugly". Considering how much code it cuts down on in this case I would say it has a certain ‘minimalist beauty’. I’ve added an answer of my own which uses both active patterns and partial application.